# How can I convert c file to cgi file?

Tags: html, c, linux, cgi

I want to convert c file to cgi file in linux but I don't understand how to do that.

And how you connect between the cgi file and the HTML page?

Answer (score 2):

CGI will execute code on the server, which returns output to the client. This means that anything your application or script prints to the standard output will be sent, so you need to make sure your application is printing out HTTP response headers (followed by the content in the form of HTML or JSON or whatever you are using).

To get it to run, it needs to be an executable, so compile it and put the compiled executable in the web server's cgi-bin (or document root, if it has been configured to allow CGI).

Answer (score 0):

I try to run a simple program that print hello world.

HTML:

```
< a href="url/cgi-bin/hello.cgi">click< /a>
```

c:

```
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n");  
    printf("<html>");
    printf("<head>");
    printf("<title>Test</title>");
    printf("</head>");
    printf("<body>");
    printf("<p>Hello world!</p>");
    printf("</body>");
    printf("</html>");
    return;
}
```

I create the cgi file in the terminal:

```
gcc hello.c -o hello.cgi
```

But when I put the file in the server, I get 404 error.